# Does Spring Cloud Config use AES key with strong RSA during client side decryption

Tags: spring-security, aes, rsa, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

### SETUP

I configured a Spring Cloud Config server backed by a local Git repo and created a Spring Boot application to consume the configuration from SCC. The config file `scc-client.yml` in Git has two plain text properties and an encrypted one, `app.secret`:

```
app:
  name: client-app
  port: 8085
  secret: '{cipher}AgCGh ... X3pTW'
```

The decryption is done on client side: `bootstrap.properties` on SCC server has `spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled=false` and `bootstrap.yml` of my Spring Boot app contains:

```
...
encrypt:
  keystore:
    location: classpath:keystore.p12
    password: kspass
    alias: client-key
    secret: kspass
  key: client-key
  rsa:
    strong: true
...
```

The keystore.p12 contains the key used to encrypt `app.secret` value. I generated the key using keytool:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias client-key -keyalg RSA -deststoretype pkcs12 -keystore src/main/resources/keystore.p12 -keysize 4096 -storepass kspass -keypass kspass
```

### QUESTION

Does Spring use hybrid RSA encryption approach while decrypting the value on the client side in the setup above?

Judging by the code some AES related components are being invoked in `o.s.s.r.c.RsaSecretEncryptor.decrypt()` method, but I'm not quite certain if that represents a full [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) with a self generated AES key being used along the way.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "full hybrid decryption". Do you have a link to a definition? `RsaSecretEncryptor` generates a random key for encryption. When you _decrypt_ obviously it needs that key again, so it's not generating anything at that point.

Comment: @DaveSyer added the link for "hybrid encryption" concept, but looks like you're familiar with it: there is RSA public-private key pair; during encryption an AES symmetric key is generated to encrypt the data, then that key is being encrypted by RSA public key, both encrypted data and encrypted AES key are being sent to client; on decryption the client uses RSA private key to obtain the AES key, which is then used to decrypt the data.

Comment: @DaveSyer so you're saying that Spring Cloud Config server generates a random AES key, encrypts it and sends to the client with the encrypted data? What if I encrypt the data using only the RSA public key (let's say with a third-party tool) and store the encrypted value to the repository. Will the Spring Boot client try to get a AES key out of the encrypted string anyway?

Comment: The client only knows how to decrypt using the same algorithm as the server. You might be lucky with a 3rd party tool, but I'm not aware of any. Please let me know if you find one. You don't really need one though do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud does employ a hybrid algorithm of the type described in the Wikipedia link. The server, or a command line client, encrypts data. The server, or a command line client, or a client app can decrypt them. Note that client-side decryption is generally the weakest, since you have to configure it with the same private key as the encyptor.